# How to prevent extra latency caused by a download

Tags: networking, qos, priority

I use [tcping](https://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php), which pings a TCP port, in order to check the connection of my computer to a certain port. The average response time of a specific address and port is **50ms** in normal connection. Now I start a download from another address using [IDM](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/), which splits the file and download the files simultaneously. My ping reply time increases to around **1500ms**. I am sure that my download increased this reply time because when I pause my download, the reply time goes back to **50ms**.

[image: Image of the problem]

I want to prevent this increase of reply time on registered addresses and ports.

I don't want to use **NetLimitter** or **NetBalancer**.

I have also tried [this](https://biztechmagazine.com/article/2010/03/boost-network-performance-windows-7-qos). I checked Wireshark and I am sure the DSCP is set but my problem is not solved.

Comment: What kind of Internet package do you have from your isp? What kind of router? How is the computer connected to the Internet?

Comment: Can you reduce the number of concurrent connections (simultaneous downloads/threads) or whatever it's called in IDM to below your number of CPUs.  Such that there is a free CPU for tcping.  Does that help?

Comment: You don't want to use the exact tools that will prevent you from saturating your connection and therefore will actually cure your problem?  Well, the only alternatives are to get rid of IDM or stop downloading things at all. Unless you tell us *why* you don't want to use them it is a bit unhelpful to rule them out.

Comment: @Julysfire My router is Linksys X3500 and The computer is connected using Wifi to the router and router is connected to the ISP using telephone line and ADSL2+

Comment: @Biswa I want to be able to choose between ports. Some ports are slower and some are faster.

Comment: @EMK no that does not change anything.

Comment: @Mokubai I want to use this solution in my own application that uses internet traffic a lot and it also needs to have a fine keep-alive with another server.

Comment: @Biswa OK. But the results are the same. The problem still exists.

Comment: @Biswa The OP's problem has nothing to do with what ports are being used. He's experiencing bandwidth contention. As the network link approaches saturation, *all* connections (regardless of port) suffer from increased latency, unless some mechanism is put in place to prioritize certain connections over others (e.g. QoS).

Comment: @Twisty I have good news for you: it turns out that's a myth. Google "bufferbloat". With smarter queueing algorithms like CoDel, you can saturate bandwidth without latency or QoS.

Answer (score 0):

If saturating either your upstream or your downstream network bandwidth causes latency to spike, it means some box in your network path (probably your broadband modem or your ISP's CMTS or DSLAM) has a well-known bug called bufferbloat, where excessive buffering on a box increases latency without benefit.

The fix for bufferbloat is to upgrade the queuing algorithm (a.k.a. queue discipline, network scheduler) of the buggy device to a latency-aware smart queueing algorithm such as FQ-CoDel.

If you can't fix the actual box with the problem, you can work around it by setting up a box with FQ-CoDel at the head of your network and tune its traffic shaping to make it a slight bottleneck in both the upstream and downstream directions. That way FQ-CoDel gets to kick in and allow TCP congestion control to work, before bloated buffer queues can build up on the buggy box.

You can do this yourself with open source router firmware distros such as LEDE (formerly OpenWrt), but if you want a turn-key solution, look at IQrouter from evenroute.com. It apparently auto-tunes its bandwidth shaping throughout the day, maximizing throughput while minimizing latency.

Many people who haven't learned about bufferbloat wrongly assume latency spikes are a natural result of saturated network links. Many people also make problematic attempts to work around bufferbloat by tweaking QoS, trying to prioritize some flows over the large flows that are triggering bloat. But solving bufferbloat directly is much better, because it improves all flows, even the big ones that were triggering bloat.

Comment: *Very* interesting. I've observed this behavior with prevalence that closes in on ubiquitous. Any explanation for why so many devices are affected by it? Do networking hardware vendors lack an incentive to fix it? Is there a "reason" in their eyes for this behavior to stay? Something else?

Comment: @Twisty RAM became cheap so engineers added more frame buffer space so frames would never have to be dropped. Problem is, TCP Congestion Control uses frame drops to detect congestion. So they acccidentally hid the congestion from TCP without realizing it. Now it's an issue of raising awareness to get middlebox makers to adopt CoDel. Google's "BBR" congestion control algorithm treats bufferbloat latency increases (not just packet drops) as a sign of congestion, as an attempt to make the endpoints smarter to work around this middlebox bug.

Comment: @Spiff I am not sure you get the CoDel right... Please have a look at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoDel There are two things: 1) with CoDel you are fixing queues under your control, not ISP and 2) the bottleneck is happening when packets from fast network travelling to a slow net, i.e. from the ISP (fast) net to a client link (slow). So CoDel on a broadband modem will not help, unfortunately...

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy The bufferbloat researchers initially developed CoDel on consumer hardware because it was easy and in their control, but they never intended it to just stop there. The goal is to get all middlebox makes and ISPs to employ smart queueing like CoDel or PIE everywhere, including CMTSes, DSLAMs, traffic shapers, etc. Mike "Dave" Taht's CoDel research is sponsored by Comcast, a giant cable ISP in the US. It takes a while to fix all the middleboxes on the Internet, but the process has begun.

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy Also, the workaround I mentioned (of making an artificial bottleneck on your network and running CoDel on it so ECN or drops happen before bloat can build up on other boxes) really does work, in both directions. Many people have successfully deployed this trick. evenroute.com has even built a commercial product around this trick (IQrouter).

Comment: @Spiff the artificial bottleneck is basically a rate limiting of your low priority traffic. So there is no magic here... The easiest way to do this is to limit the bandwidth in your downloading software. See "Speed Limiter" tab in the original question.

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy No, fixing bufferbloat keeps latency down even without QoS to prioritize one flow over another. Or even if your high-priority flow is the one that was triggering the bloat. That's the beauty of it. No matter which flow is saturating the link, fixing bufferbloat makes them all low latency.

Comment: @Spiff earlier you wrote "making an artificial bottleneck on your network and running CoDel on it". That "artificial bottleneck" is called "rate/bandwidth limit". Do you agree?

Answer (score -1):

Each Internet connection has two directions: from user to the Internet and back. Each direction is independent in therms of QoS and route the packet traverse.

Setting a priority on the OUTGOING packets does not change the priority of INCOMING packets. The priority and QoS of INCOMING packets are still under control of your ISP.

If you have an option to prioritize your traffic on the ISP side - you should try this. Otherwise, your only option is to rate limit you incoming "best effort" traffic, so you always have some bandwidth for your pings or other "high priority" traffic.

Unfortunately, that is not a solution, but I hope it will help you to understand the issue.

Comment: So you are suggesting me to reserve some bandwidth myself. Right?

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee that is the only option if 1) you have no control over QoS on the ISP side and 2) the bottleneck is incoming traffic (from your ISP to you). The QoS configurations will help only when the bottleneck is outgoing traffic (from you to ISP).